# Create <li> for each element of array

Tags: jquery, html

I'm not sure if what I'm trying is right. I got this JS code

```
var main = [{
 title:'Title 1',
 tagsProject: ('tag1', 'tag2'),
 content: 'Content1'
},{
 title:'Title 2',
 tagsProject: ('tag5', 'tag6', 'tag1'),
 content: 'Content2'
},{
 title:'Title grid 3',
 tagsProject: ('tag4'),
 content: 'Content3'
},

container = $('<div />', {class:'container'});

$.each(main, function(i, e){
 var item = $('<div />', {
   class:'item',
   html:'<div><h2>' + e.title + '</h2></div>' +
   '<div class="content"><p>' + e.content + '</p><ul class="tags"></ul></div></div>'
})

container.append(item);

});

container.appendTo($('main'));
```

And just this HTML code

```
<main></main>
```

When I load the page, my JS generates the rest and HTML code now will look like this

```
<main>
 <div class="container">

  <div class ="item">
   <div>
    <h2>Title 1</h2>
   </div>
   <div class="content">
    <p>Content1</p>
    <ul class="tags"></ul>
   </div>
  </div>

  <div class ="item">
   <div>
    <h2>Title 2</h2>
   </div>
   <div class="content">
    <p>Content2</p>
    <ul class="tags"></ul>
   </div>
  </div>

  <div class ="item">
   <div>
    <h2>Title 3</h2>
   </div>
   <div class="content">
    <p>Content3</p>
    <ul class="tags"></ul>
   </div>
  </div>

 </div>
</main>
```

There you have a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/tanaan/24kzwmz0/

First of all, I'm not sure if the way I have variable `tagsProject` is treated as an array. I think so, but not 100% sure.

I'd like to add each tag in a `<li>` nested in `<ul class="tags">`for each element and get this final HTML code

```
<main>
 <div class="container">

  <div class ="item">
   <div>
    <h2>Title 1</h2>
   </div>
   <div class="content">
    <p>Content1</p>
    <ul class="tags">
     <li><a href="tag1">tag1</a></li>
     <li><a href="tag2">tag2</a></li>
    </ul>
   </div>
  </div>

  <div class ="item">
   <div>
    <h2>Title 2</h2>
   </div>
   <div class="content">
    <p>Content2</p>
    <ul class="tags">
     <li><a href="tag5">tag5</a></li>
     <li><a href="tag6">tag6</a></li>
     <li><a href="tag1">tag1</a></li>
    </ul>
   </div>
  </div>

  <div class ="item">
   <div>
    <h2>Title 3</h2>
   </div>
   <div class="content">
    <p>Content3</p>
    <ul class="tags">
     <li><a href="tag4">tag4</a></li>
    </ul>
   </div>
  </div>

 </div>
</main>
```

I have tried it by adding this code at the end of the JS

```
var cList = $('ul.tags')
$.each(main, function(i, e)
{
    var li = $('<li/>')
        .appendTo(cList);
    var aaa = $('<a/>')
        .text(e.tagsProject[i])
        .appendTo(li);

    cList.append(item);
});
```

But it adds only one `<li>` with just the first letter plus cannot make the `<href>`

You can see it here https://jsfiddle.net/tanaan/24kzwmz0/1/

Any help would be much appreciated, I'm bit lost.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for two loops `each()` since you could get all the data you want in the first loop.

Hope this helps.

```js
var main = [{
  title:'Title 1',
  tagsProject: ['tag1', 'tag2'],
  content: 'Content1'
},{
  title:'Title 2',
  tagsProject: ['tag5', 'tag6', 'tag1'],
  content: 'Content2'
},{
  title:'Title 3',
  tagsProject: ['tag4'],
  content: 'Content3'
}];
var container = $('<div />', {class:'container'});

$.each(main, function(i, e){
  var cList = $('<ul class="tags"/>');
  
  e.tagsProject.map(function(tag){ 
    var link = $('<a/>').text(tag).prop('href', tag); 
    $('<li/>').append(link).appendTo(cList);
  });

  var item = $('<div />', {
    class:'item',
    html:'<div><h2>' + e.title + '</h2></div>' +
    '<div class="content"><p>' + e.content + '</p></div></div>'
  });
  
  item.find('.content').append(cList);
  container.append(item);
});

container.appendTo($('main'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.js"></script>
<main></main>
```

Answer (score 2):

There are several problems with your code:

1. `cList.append(item)` produces the error: `item is not defined`.
2. Accessing `e.tagsProject[i]` will treat `e.tagsProject` as an array of characters, incrementing the letter being accessed for each item in `main[]`.

---

Removing `cList.append(item)` produces the above behaviour. But you can get around this by simply using `e.tagsProject` as a string literal, rather than an array.

Please see the [**updated jsFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/24kzwmz0/3/) or the snippet below:

```js
var main = [{
 title:'Title 1',
 tagsProject: ('tag1', 'tag2'),
 content: 'Content1'
},{
 title:'Title 2',
 tagsProject: ('tag5', 'tag6', 'tag1'),
 content: 'Content2'
},{
 title:'Title 3',
 tagsProject: ('tag4'),
 content: 'Content3'
}],

container = $('<div />', {class:'container'});

$.each(main, function(i, e){
 var item = $('<div />', {
   class:'item',
   html:'<div><h2>' + e.title + '</h2></div>' +
   '<div class="content"><p>' + e.content + '</p><ul class="tags"></ul></div></div>'
})
container.append(item);
});

container.appendTo($('main'));

var cList = $('ul.tags')
$.each(main, function(i, e)
{
    var li = $('<li/>')
        .appendTo(cList);
    var aaa = $('<a/>')
        .attr('href', e.tagsProject)
        .text(e.tagsProject)
        .appendTo(li);

    //cList.append(item);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<main></main>
```

Comment: Thanks very much BenM. Seems I was quite close plus also right assuming the way I set `tagsProject` variable is treated as an array. May I include a `<href>` with same value as the tag name to get something like `<a href="tag1">tag1</a>` ? Many thanks for your help, you legend mate.

Comment: sure thing, `.attr`. How stupid I am! Was trying `.href(e.tagsProject)` O_o  Thanks a mil, sir!

Comment: Sorry mate, I've just noticed that we are getting the last element of each array and having them repeated inside each item. No one is right. Content 1 should have tag1, tag2. Content 2, tag5, tag6, tag1 and Content 3, just tag4. Instead we have tag2, tag1 and tag4 in each content. any idea why? Thanks again

Comment: Could be because, as I feared, tagsProject is not treated as an array itself but a I simple string? It is quite weird what the code returns, not sure how to  interpret it. ):

Comment: Forget about it, @Zakaria Acharki's answer do the work perfectly. Thanks again anyway Ben.

Answer (score 1):

@BenM's answer works, though what I understood from the question was how to create an element for each tag, not all tags. This does it for you, I used `map` to turn each tag into an HTML string, and then joined those and created an element to be appended.

Of course, you may wanna clean the code up.

Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/24kzwmz0/4/

Comment: Hi casraf, thanks for the answer and sorry if I haven't explained myself clear enough. I was looking what @BenM posted. I really appreciate your help tho, it is allways good to know different options in case I need something like what you shared. Many thanks. Cheers.

Comment: I've been double checking your code and, despite it is not exactly what I was looking for (not a big problem cuz can re-use your approach for other situations), I've noticed you are just getting the elements from the first `tagsProjects`array and using them in each Content, but you are ignoring the other arrays that should be used for each item. Any idea why? Thanks a lot

Comment: I'm sorry, I kind of missed the first each in the code. Okay, looks like you're looping twice for the elements, which 1: you should just do it in the same loop, and 2: if you still decide to use different loops, you will need to specify which `cList` you will be appending to on each one.

Comment: Also I'm not sure why all the `<li>`s duplicate, the code is kinda messy and I didn't really put much time into it

Comment: Forget about it, mate. @Zakaria Acharki just hit the jackpot! Thanks a mil anyway.